# How to use SUM and DINSTINCT with GreenDao querybuilder?

Tags: android, greendao, greendao-generator, greendao3

I want to get the sum of total rows in a column of a table in SqlLite Database. I am using GreenDao Library. I know I Have to use `SUM`.  But I don't know how to use it with GreenDao `queryBuilder`. Can anybody help me? and also DISTINCT.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it. Assume there is the Company entity and it has the numOfEmployees field:

```
Cursor cursor = daoSession.getDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT SUM(" + Company Dao.Properties.NumOfEmployees.columnName + ") FROM " + Company Dao.TABLENAME, new String []{});
cursor.moveToFirst();
long result = cursor.getLong(0);
```

Note that you could hardcode the column and table names above, but this is way cleaner.